Dissipative semigroup implies contraction?
I find myself in an odyssey, I want to show that:

Let $H$ be a reflexive space and $S(t)$ be the semigroup generated by $A$. Show that if $A$ is dissipative, then $S(t)$ is a contraction over $H$.

I have been trying this test for several days now, without any success. Sorry for not uploading a preview of the demonstration, I lost the idea and I can't express it. I would appreciate your help, thank you very much in advance.

Have you tried looking at the Lumer-Phillips theorem? I think some more information about $A$ is required as well.

What is a reflective space? do you mean reflexive?

I think you need that $A$ is $m$-dissipative, i.e. dissipative and $R(I-A)=X$. See Theorem 3.15 in Engel's book. Also note that you do not need the assumption $A$ being densely defined since this true for $m$-dissipative operators in reflexive spaces (Corollary 3.20)
